# What is Tom's sickness?

Tags: knowledge

1:3

☀ 1:3

1:3

❄1:3

replace [☀2,❄1]:

What is Tom's sickness?

Disclaimer: Highly `knowledge`able

A funny hint:

> Did you maybe guess what the first four lines mean by themselves? Well, SOMEONE didn't....

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first five lines are a reference to

> https://youtu.be/MCuCBt24hAk this video, namely the animation at 9:39. The video is of the game Telestrations, played with various Youtube content creators; each player in the game receives either an animation explaining a concept (with no narration) or a verbal explanation of a topic (with no accompanying animation). That player then makes a corresponding animation or verbal explanation, which is then passed on to the next player.
> Jabril, the player at the aforementioned timestamp, is the person referenced in the hint; missing the fact that ☀❄ refer to seasons, he simply reads out *"Flower, 1 to 3, sun, 1 to 3, leaf, 1 to 3, snowflake, 1 to 3, replaces from sun 2 to snowflake 1 in the sequence."* This is what the first five lines represent.

which means "Tom" must be

> Tom Scott, who talked about **bartender's elbow.**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This looks like the correct answer, but could you add more detail (about the context of the video, and why the first five lines are a reference to it)?

Comment: I've added a further explanation of what the first five lines mean in the context of the video. Hopefully this is a more complete answer now.